# Can't Link to SQLite3 static library

Tags: c++, sqlite, gcc, linker, makefile

I have a static library, libsqlite3.a, that i want to link to my small program.
my make file is as shown below:

```
CPP = g++

sources = main.cpp
objects = main.o

included = -IC:/SQLite-lib/include
linked = -LC:/SQLite-lib/ -lsqlite3

main : $(objects)
    $(CPP) $(linked) $(objects) -o main

main.o : $(sources)
    $(CPP) $(included) -c main.cpp
```

I keep getting this kind of error message:

```
g++ -LC:/SQLite-lib/libsqlite3.a main.o -o main
main.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x42): undefined reference to `sqlite3_open'
main.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x7d): undefined reference to `sqlite3_close'
main.o:main.cpp:(.text+0xe7): undefined reference to `sqlite3_close'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [main] Error 1
```

What am I doing wrong? I use Win XP SP3, GCC 4.6.2.

Comment: The makefile and the output does not match!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must always place libraries after the files you link. Change the linking line in the makefile to:

```
main : $(objects)
    $(CPP) $(objects) -o main $(linked)
```

That should work.

Answer (score 0):

Your link arguments are incorrect. `-L` is used to specify *directories* (search path) where libraries can be found. `-l` is used to specify what libraries to link to.

```
g++ -LC:/some/lib/path main.o -o main -lsqlite3
```

Comment: I don't know, the error message in your Q doesn't match your makefile any more, please update that _and leave the original Makefile and error message_. Also, using `$(CPP)` for a C++ compiler is a bad idea. Use `$(CXX)`. CPP is for the C pre-processor, not C++. (And -lsqlite3 needs to go after `main.o`.)